# Can we edit photos and add text on it? Is it halal?

Tags: sharia, photos

Assalamu alaikum,

I'm running a blog with some articles and Islamic photos in it. Was just wondering if we can add text on photos (humans, animals) just for fun? Just to make people laugh...

Like http://9gag.com

Just wanted to follow the website like this... will that be halal?

Comment: The site you are referring to contains obscene material brother.
You should be careful what you are posting

Comment: As long as you are not editing the looks of those humans to make people laugh, it should be Okay. Don't make fun of how people look, because they are a creation of Allah (SWT).

Answer (score 2):

InshaAllah it will be halal, just insure you follow the following rules:

- Like Shia_Sunni______UNITY said, don't mock specific people as that is not allowed in Islam. However that only applies to known people, if the picture of a random person that isn't known it should be fine (just checked the website you posted out, it is all of actors mostly which isn't wrong, since they are actors and part of their job is making us laugh).
- Do not post nude photos or non-Islamic photos (showing private parts) or provocative photos that might turn people on.
- If you believe that hand drawn faces are haram (I personally don't) then you shouldn't post such images, only pictures that are representation of real people.
- Most of these websites have advertisement that is pretty catchy and adult oriented, you need to think about that before starting such website as if you want to make money those are the type of ads you will have to serve, which isn't Islamically appropriate. My suggestion would be that you start a website that is more reputable.

My final opinion is to be safe than sorry and start on a different website that shows your skills on something you love working on, which will make you money down the road as you grow.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule (Islamic rule), mocking of people is not considered as a competent act (even regarding mocking of non-Muslim people).

So, for instance, it has mentioned in the holy Quran (a-Hujurat: 11) regarding mocking that:

> يا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا لا يَسْخَرْ قَوْمٌ مِنْ قَوْمٍ عَسى‏
>   أَنْ يَكُونُوا خَيْراً مِنْهُمْ وَ لا نِساءٌ مِنْ نِساءٍ عَسى‏ أَنْ
>   يَكُنَّ خَيْراً مِنْهُنَّ وَ لا تَلْمِزُوا أَنْفُسَكُمْ وَ لا
>   تَنابَزُوا بِالْأَلْقابِ بِئْسَ الاسْمُ الْفُسُوقُ بَعْدَ الْإِيمانِ
>   وَ مَنْ لَمْ يَتُبْ فَأُولئِكَ هُمُ الظَّالِمُونَ (11)
>
> O you who have believed, let not a people ridicule [another] people;
>   perhaps they may be better than them; nor let women ridicule [other]
>   women; perhaps they may be better than them. And do not insult one
>   another and do not call each other by [offensive] nicknames. Wretched
>   is the name of disobedience after [one's] faith. And whoever does not
>   repent - then it is those who are the wrongdoers. (11)

**According to the view of Grand Ayatollah Khamenei (as a Marja'al-Taqlid of shia), it is not permissible (mocking…), and the right humans (humanity) ought to be observed and Muslims ought to control themselves from these affairs..**

Of course in accordance with the ruling above, it seems that there mustn't be a problem is doing that for animals.., but we are not allowed to do that for the humans.

---

References:

- [http://tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/49:11)
- [www.porseman.org](http://www.porseman.org)
- [http://ghiam-el.ir](http://ghiam-el.ir/2014/10)

Comment: Question was not asked about specific Fiqa (like shia) or specific personality (like Grand Ayatullah Khamene). Give answer only from Sunnah which is followable for all not only for shias.

Comment: As Umar has stated, although I highly respect your views and also the views of Imam Ayatullah, but, here in IslamSE, the words of the prophet(pbuh) and the words of the creator matter more, and hence your answer would be considered as a mere opinion. That's It, even though your trying your level best to help others by sharing the right answer. Please try your level best to quote from Qur'an and Hadith(words of Prophet(pbuh)) from now on. Insha Allah.

Comment: You mentioned some nice points, mate. I agree you, but I reckon u agree that: commonly, Maraja’al-Taqlid declare their viewpoints base on Qur’an and ahadith (directly or indirectly). Since perhap occasionally we cannot directly some matters in ahadith (E.g. using mobile…), then Maraja’al-Taqlid infer them by referring to different verses and hadiths. (I reckon u agree my notion) / Anyhow, thanks for paying attention to the mentioned matter. So, I added a related verse to my response which could be related to the mentioned matter.

Comment: Otherwise totally I absolutely agree you that at the initial step we ought to refer to the holy Quran and authentic hadiths. Good luck mate.